# Use enum from other class without classname::

Tags: c++, enums

I have enum inside public part of some class **A**. I want to use this enum in class **B**. Is it a way to make it accessible without specifying *A::enum_value*? So I can use just *enum_value*.

```
using A::enumname;
```

inside class *B* doesn't compile.

Comment: Do you can simply remove the enum from class A?

Answer (score 1):

```
If you only need certain values, you can do:

struct B {
  static const A::enumname 
    enum_value1 = A::enum_value1,
    enum_value2 = A::enum_value2;  // etc.
};
```

If you can modify A, you can extract the enum into a base class that can be used by both A and B:

```
struct AEnum {
  enum enumname { enum_value1, enum_value2 };
};

struct A : AEnum {
};

struct B : BEnum {
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to directly import all the enum values from one place to another. In this case I'd suggest wrapping `A`'s enum into a nested class, and then typedeffing *that* into `B`.

For example:

```
class A
{
public:
    struct UsefulEnumName
    {
        enum Type { BAR };
    };
};

class B
{
    typedef A::UsefulEnumName UsefulEnumName;
    UsefulEnumName::Type foo() const { return UsefulEnumName::BAR; }
};
```